# QMAIL - Do not handle emails for my domain

Tags: domain-name-system, g-suite, email-server, email, mx-record

How can I stop q-mail from handling my domain specific emails?

For example, I have a blog installed on my server and it uses PHP to make use of the mail() function to send out emails.

```
mail('email@my-domain.com', 'subject', 'message');
```

But when it sends email with @my-domain.com it doesn't leave the server to check what the MX records are, it just sends it locally because that address exists in its records some how.

I ask because I have started making use of GMail as my mail service provider and I need emails to arrive there rather than just stay in the server.

I hope I have made this clear as I am having trouble trying to find terms that I can use to serach via Google!

Thanks all

Comment: Why is this tagged "php"?

Comment: I am making use of the PHP mail function.

Comment: @Abs I read that. But it's tagged just because you *mentioned* it. The question's not tagged "google" or "mail" either...

Comment: I can see where you are coming from, I have changed to google apps now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qmail keeps it's configurations files in /var/qmail/control:

```
grep YOUR_DOMAIN /var/qmail/control/*
```

Remove your domain from the following files:

/var/qmail/control/rcpthosts
/var/qmail/control/locals

Comment: I think you actually want to leave the name in rcpthosts, otherwise qmail will reject the messages outright because it's not responsible for the domain.  Removing from locals tells qmail that the domain is not handled locally and it should try to deliver through smtproutes, and mx records.